# How to detect 01-Jan-01 dates in pandas from csv

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have the following csv, saved as `test.txt`:

```
title, arbitrarydate, value
hello, 01-Jan-01, 314159
```

running the following code

```
dataframe = pd.read_csv('pandatestcsv.txt', parse_dates = True)
print dataframe.dtypes
```

gives this output

```
title            object
arbitrarydate    object
value             int64
dtype: object
```

Why does pandas fail to detect that arbitrarydate is a date column? How can I make it parse this correctly? I want it to detect that arbitrarydate is a date column for me, I don't want to specify in advance which columns contain dates.

Comment: Is it possible to make this work without specifying which columns contain dates in advance?

Answer (score 0):

For me works:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u"""title,arbitrarydate,value
hello,01-Jan-01,314159"""
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), parse_dates=['arbitrarydate'])
print (df)
   title arbitrarydate   value
0  hello    2001-01-01  314159

print (df.dtypes)
title                    object
arbitrarydate    datetime64[ns]
value                     int64
dtype: object
```

Another solution is add position of column as parameter to `parse_dates`:

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), parse_dates=[1])
print (df)
   title arbitrarydate   value
0  hello    2001-01-01  314159

print (df.dtypes)
title                    object
arbitrarydate    datetime64[ns]
value                     int64
dtype: object
```

[Docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#datetime-handling).

You can specify all columns in `parse_dates`, but it is dangerous, because sometimes some integers can be parsed as datetimes, e.g.:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u"""title,arbitrarydate,value
hello,01-Jan-01,2000"""
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), parse_dates = [0,1,2])
print (df)
   title arbitrarydate      value
0  hello    2001-01-01 2000-01-01

print (df.dtypes)
title                    object
arbitrarydate    datetime64[ns]
value            datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Comment: Is it possible to get this to work without specifying in advance which columns contain dates?

Comment: I think no, `parse_dates = True` is used if need parse datetimeindex.